# How to hide certain links in forum?

Tags: nodes, users

I am wondering what is the best way to preserve viewing certain url patterns in forum posts only for authenticated users? So that guests can see something like "please log in to view the link", as per most stand-alone forums?

Comment: Are those links internal or external? And are they in Link field or body filed content?

Comment: They are external and in body field.

Answer (score 0):

Im not finding a module for that but what I would do is use jQuery to convert all links tags and their content in the "Content area" to [Please login to view this link] this is only loaded if the user is anonymous.

The function `.replaceWith()` http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/ can be used

Comment: Can you please elaborte on how to use jQuery to do so?

Comment: use Jquery `.replaceWith()`